# Problem after joining meshes

Tags: mesh, transparency, unity

After I've joined 3 meshes into a single mesh with ctrl+j, part of it becomes transparent after I import it to Unity (see left side of the image). What could cause this and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like back-face culling to me, which would make sense if the normals of the bottom object were inverted. Try selecting everything in edit mode and pressing Ctrl N to recalculate the normals before exporting.

Comment: Did you have any modifiers on the meshed before you joined them?

Comment: @gandalf3 It's strange, I had tried doing that earlier and it didn't work. Now after some more modifications to the model I rejoined the objects and found different parts to be transparent than before, and recalculating the normals fixed it this time. Thanks.

Comment: @Denis Nope, no modifiers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the normals of the bottom part are inverted, resulting in a transparent look due to [back-face culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling).

Try recalculating the normals with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) with everything selected (<kbd>A</kbd>). Note that it's possible to create [topology which cannot have consistent normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/599), which could be why this didn't work for you before.

Comment: I've an object showing transparent faces (and black triangles), which I tried to fix after a Join. The object is not detected as non-manifold, normals are consistent and the problems are still present.

Comment: @mins this is a wild guess, but is it possible you have a copy of your mesh overlapping in the same spot?

Comment: Not the case. I found a bypass: Exporting the object (x3d) and reimporting it to create a clean mesh.

Comment: @mins glad you got it working, happy new year :)